# XP computer going into standby, all timers set to Never

Tags: windows-xp, standby

Received fault report for this XP box I support. Staff report it 'turns off overnight' and needs turning back on in the morning. Closer inspection the network card seems to be sleeping, and then the system follows suit fairly soon after.

I'm remoting into this machine on LogMeIn, I have to use the Wake On LAN feature to wake it and can use it for possibly 5/10 minutes before it'll go into standby. You catch a glimpse of the 'Preparing to standby' notice before the network connection dies.

Going into standby has happened while system was (remotely) in use on one occasion.

I then have to wait 10 mins for LogMeIn to refresh and let me send another wake up request. All timers in power options set to Never, nothing jumping out at me from the system event log, disabled any sleep functions on the network card under device manager.

Any ideas?

Comment: Were there any changes before this started to happen? Something new installed? Viruses?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, although saying that I don't get enough time to check properly. On a side note I can't see this as a productive activity for a virus!

Comment: Yeah. It is not impossible that this is a malware. Not they only steal credit card numbers, but also can do this random bad things. I only can advice check system log. Not that it is great on XP, but at least try to get any useful data.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth while to try running the below command to disable hibernation entirely.

CMD > powercfg -h off

Let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the BIOS (will require a site visit). Some of them have options to wake/sleep at certain times that you will have to disable.